# How do you add a newline character in a string at specific indices?

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string:

```
String testString= "For the time being, programming is a consumer job, assembly line coding is the norm, and what little exciting stuff is being performed is not going to make it compared to the mass-marketed cräp sold by those who think they can surf on the previous half-century's worth of inventions forever"
```

**like this:  For the time being, programmi \n........\n.......\n**

After each length of 20 characters in this string, I want to put a newline character \n for display in a TextView in Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must have to use regex for achieve your task its fast and efficient. Try below code:-

```
String str = "....";
String parsedStr = str.replaceAll("(.{20})", "$1\n");
```

The (.{20}) will capture a group of 20 characters. The $1 in the second will put the content of the group. The \n will be then appended to the 20 characters which have been just matched.

Comment: genius, im thinking about revoking my answer^^

Comment: I do like short code - but this (due to regex compilation - is considerably slower (factor 6) that my solution.

Comment: Shorter: `str.replaceAll(".{20}", "$0\n")`

Answer (score 3):

How about something like that?

```
String s = "...whateverstring...";  

for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 20) {
    s = new StringBuffer(s).insert(i, "\n").toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know there is a technically better solution to use a [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) and the [`insert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#insert%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) method for that class, or even regex, but I'll show you a different algorithmic approach using [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

```
String s = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789";

int offset = 0; // each time you add a new character, string has "shifted"
for (int i = 20; i + offset < s.length(); i += 20) {
    // take first part of string, add a new line, and then add second part
    s = s.substring(0, i + offset) + "\n" + s.substring(i + offset);
    offset++;
}

System.out.println(s);
```

The result is this:

```
12345678901234567890
12345678901234567890
12345678901234567890
12345678901234567890
12345678901234567890
1234567890123456789
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int done = 0;
    while( done < s.length() ){
        int todo = done + 20 < s.length() ? 20 : s.length() - done;
        sb.append( s.substring( done, done + todo ) ).append( '\n' );
        done += todo;
    }
    String result = sb.toString();
```

This also appends a newline at the end, but you can modify it easily to avoid that.